# Run Kurento application

Tags: java, maven, webrtc, kurento

I have set up kurento media server in an ubuntu server and , i compile the  examples using the below commands,

```
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java.git
cd kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-one2one-call-advanced
mvn compile exec:java
```

I need to run this application alive all the time.even i close the terminal.How is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tutorials can be installed to run as a service in your Linux box. If you run `mvn clean install`, you'll get a *zip* file in each tutorial's `target` folder. Unzip that file and execute the `install.sh` script. There is a README.md file that goes inside the zipped file with some instructions.

Comment: i executed install.sh,but there is an error /etc/init.d/kurento-one2one-call-recording: 92: kill: No such process

Comment: which port output the page?

Comment: You can see the port in the project's [pom](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java/blob/master/kurento-one2one-call-advanced/pom.xml#L47), or you can execute `sudo netstat -pant | grep java` and that should show you the port where your Java app is listening.

Comment: This showing only tcp6       0      0 :::8888                 :::*                    LISTEN      17413/kurento-media no other ports.why?

Comment: The started service automatically stops in few seconds

Comment: But you must surely get an exception. Perhaps you can investigate that.

Comment: How to trace the exception?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100689/discussion-between-shijin-and-igracia).